# Is it possible to start an intent from a broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to launch the mapping application when an SMS arrives containing map coordinates. I have my broadcastreceiver set up with no problems and as I understand it I need to do something like:

```
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:" + latitude  + "," + longitude +"?z=10");
                Intent mapintent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(mapintent);
```

but Eclipse is telling me that startActivity isn't defined for the type BroadcastReceiver. How do I go about starting the intent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`startActivity()` is on the `Context` class, you just need to use an instance of Context.  You get one passed in the `onReceive()` method.

Comment: I've tried using context.startActivity(intent) but the application force closes with a java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4  error caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4

Comment: Solved that issue, also needed to add                     mapintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Answer (score 2):

For completeness:

As mbaird (and Eugene) said use the context from the activity passed in the OnCreate() - final solution looks like:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:" + latitude  + "," + longitude +"?z=10");

Intent mapintent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

mapintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

context.startActivity(mapintent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have an instance of Context somewhere around. Context has startActivity method that you can use.